# ngFor detection from firebaes

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngfor

I have a page chat, with different person who the user have chat with the last message date.

getFunction from firebase work as well , I can see the new array in the consol with right information , but in the html page , I need to change view and come back to get right information , I have test changeDetection but it dont Work ,I have test ngzone.run() it work but with delay ..;

```
this.usersList.push({user:resulta.data(),message:resultaa.data()});
```

The html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let usr of usersList">
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of push try to spread it;

```
this.usersList = [
...this.usersList,
{
user:resulta.data(),
message: resultaa.data()
}]
```

Comment: same issue , I need to change view and come back to see the change...

Comment: what do you mean by come back to see the change?

Comment: For exemple In my Chrome browser , I switch tab and go back to the localhost tab

Answer (score 0):

With this line `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges` after the array-`push`, it doesn‘t work?

The problem is, that Angular's change detection mechanism doesn’t handle the content change of an array (push/pop). So you must *manually* notify Angular about a change.

The official documentation about **Angular-ChangeDetector** you can read [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)

Another way, is with `slice()`, where you can see on this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39201747) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36247170).

Comment: this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges work , but with delay, blank array and after 2 seconde it comme with right information